# In Flutter, Why BuildOwner.buildScope traverses the dirty list in depth order?

Tags: flutter

In flutter, the method `setState` will invoke `BuildOwner.buildScope`. About this method `buildScope`, the official documentation says:

> This mechanism prevents build methods from transitively requiring
>   other build methods to run, potentially causing infinite loops. The
>   dirty list is processed after `callback` returns, building all the
>   elements that were marked as dirty using [scheduleBuildFor], in depth
>   order. If elements are marked as dirty while this method is running,
>   they must be deeper than the `context` node, and deeper than any
>   previously-built node in this pass.

I have two questions about this,

1. How does this mechanism work ？
2. Why does it traverses the dirty list in depth order ?

Does anyone know ? thanks.